# Defining jenkinsfile script path when creating pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to checkout my repository from github.I create a pipeline and chose
Here are the steps that I followed

1. Click on ***new item*** on jenkins main page
2. Entered name and chose pipeline form list
3. Under ***Pipeline*** I chose definition as ***Pipeline script from SCM***
4. Chose ***SCM*** as ***GIT***
5. Under ***Repository*** entered the ***Repository Url*** with the credentials
6. Under ***Branches to build*** entered by branch as ****/my_branch_here***
   [image]

Now the jenkisfile does not belong in the root directory.Is there a way to naviagate to the directory using jenkins UI

Comment: Where is the documentation for this? Looking at https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/ I don't see any reference to `scriptPath` (as used in the Job DSL).

Comment: in jenkins 2.4 I don't see any scriptpath textbox

Answer (score 2):

From Jenkins site,

> In the Script Path field, specify the location (and name) of your
>   Jenkinsfile. This location is the one that Jenkins checks out/clones
>   the repository containing your Jenkinsfile, which should match that of
>   the repository’s file structure. **The default value of this field
>   assumes that your Jenkinsfile is named "Jenkinsfile" and is located at
>   the root of the repository.**

Jenkinsfile should be committed to SCM and put the relative path of the Jenkinsfile in SCM repository root. Careful on the name(Jenkinsfile or JenkinsFile)!

Answer (score 2):

The **Script Path** is the relative location of your Jenkinsfile in the git repository (OR in the agent's workspace directory). so if the Jenkinsfile lives in */git-repository/your-project/folder1* then the **Script Path** should be: *folder1/Jenkinsfile*

Answer (score 1):

In this case , you can keep your jenkins file into the existing workspace location

```
<<Jenkins-Installation-Dir>>/workspace/<<Job-Name>>
```

Comment: I still get this error java.io.FileNotFoundException.What is usually the jenkins installation directory.I tried using C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins

Comment: Jenkins installation directory means where you installed the current jenkins. Hope you installed jenkins in your windows machine.  You may  keep jenkins-file in this location and try to execute "C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/Workspace/<<YOur Job Name>>"

Comment: Is there a way to refresh the workspace.I cannot see the file in the folder

Comment: It won't be available intiially, you have to create and put the JenkinsFile in that location. Else you have to commit the same file in GIT repo. so next time if you are running the job it will take the file from your project repo.

Comment: Stil doesn't work.I tried creating the file directly also tried pushing to the git repository.I can only get it to work when it is in the root folder

Answer (score 0):

Just enter location of Jenkinsfile to the field `my/directory/Jenkinsfile`