# Where is the documentation for git scriptPath if creating a job DSL pipeline?

Tags: jenkins

E.g. if you were creating the Job DSL for a pipeline such as mentioned here [Defining jenkinsfile script path when creating pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719842/defining-jenkinsfile-script-path-when-creating-pipeline) where is the documentation for `scriptPath`?

I don't see anything here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/

Answer (score 0):

as described in the comment, the script path is the relative location of your Jenkinsfile in the git repository.

here you can find information about Jenkinsfile:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/

here you can find information about syntax:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

in addition in your Jenkins gui once created a pipeline item, configure it and you can find the link to "Pipeline Syntax" that help you to generate a script.