# How to set Script Path with multiple repositories in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I will add multiple git repositories:[image]

So I am wondering how I should set the Script Path of Jenkins?[image]
Maybe like this: [repository url]/jenkinfile ?

Comment: looks like it was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719842/defining-jenkinsfile-script-path-when-creating-pipeline

Comment: @AleksandrNeizvestnyi Thanks, but I think it for single repository. As the path is relative path, it is difficult to specify which repository I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I did not figure out how to run multipe repositories in pipeline. But I solved my problem by adding another JenkinsFile in the repository and set the Script Path to the new JenkinsFile (I named it as JenksFileTest).